# If Wix Bundle is deleted, How to uninstall it from control panel

Tags: c#, installation, wix

I am new to WIX installer creating, I have create a WIX Bundle, which installs a WIX installer item. (MSI file). The Bundle has a custom UI which allow user to select features which is installed.
It works OK.
But there is problem, when the WIX Bundle (including MSI file, Setup file) is send to user, the user use the bundle to install the application. **Then the User Delete the Bundle**. After some days, the user go to the Control panel, try to uninstall the Bundle, It doesn't work, logs(event viewer) shows that the uninstalling process try to find the original Bundle file (in original location), But it has already been deleted by user. The uninstalling is blocked there.
How to handle this problem?

I have no idea, the WIX Bundle has a custom UI(Created by WPF tech), If the Bundle(all installing media file) is removed, the Uninstalling System seems to need it.

Here is more detail, I have tried to get some advances.

I need to get the path of the .exe installer or its folder's path. We were using WixBundleOriginalSource, but that variable does not change if the install has already run - it always refers to the original source (as you would expect). So subsequent installations always expect to use the original folder.

Here is scenario.   Setup.exe executed in FolderA, installed app.
then the user moved the setup.exe(and *.msi) to FolderB.  then click Setup.exe again to install(repair) it.

I found that the code: this.Engine.StringVariables["WixBundleOriginalSource"]
always returns the FolderA.

How can get the exe current folder (FolderB) in code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.